# jQuery datepicker field value not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a field on which I have implemented [jQuery Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but if I assign a value on that field its shows in the chrome's developer tool...

[image]

But its not showing on the front end.

I know we can set a default date like this with the datepicker option `setDate`:

`$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate", '29-10-2016');`

But the date is coming from database and I cannot hard code it... So is there any way I can add a value and it will show up on front end unless user changes and set another date?

`<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="datepicker" value="25-10-2016">`

Comment: What backend are you using?

Comment: Im using PHP + MySQL

Comment: I'm .Net developer but as the same issue  I just want to suggest something.lets say you get data from database then the only thing is to run client script from backend.

Comment: Actually its not a backend issue... So you can suggest

Comment: Or else you can get date and keep into hidden input and on document ready can set date to datepicker object

Comment: I have this option in mind as Plan B but there must be a way to use field's `value`

Comment: you can try like this `$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate",$('#date').val());`

Comment: That is exactly what I suggest but it looks as plan b

Comment: @KandarpKalavadia have tried it before... Didn't worked for me!

Comment: @KandarpKalavadia if I try `alert($( "#date" ).val());` for testing it shows empty alert. It seems that when I activate the datepicker widget on the field the `value` doesn't work anyway

Comment: In my case it was a compatibility issue. It was not working on Firefox, but on Chrome and Safari the default date was showing up properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way but still doesn't feel its the correct way, but for now this will do the trick for me.

I'm posting this answer to help other and will wait and see anyone else come up with the best and efficient solution for this question.

Since I'm using PHP so I just put this on my page to set the date for that field. I can add more lines if I have more date fields in my page...

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#date').datepicker('setDate', '<?php echo $date; ?>');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem happen because javascript require date input in format "yyyy-MM-dd", regardless format you use to display the value.

So your code should be like this :

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="datepicker" value="2016-10-25">
```

or

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="datepicker" value="<?php echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d"); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting value from $('#date').val() then there is problem in back end , date is not coming from back-end. If there is value in input field like

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="datepicker" value="25-10-2016">
```

Then you can use below code .

```js
$(function(){   
  
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"} );
 $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate",$('#date').val());
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="date" id="date" class="datepicker" value="25-10-2016">
```

Comment: But if you see my answer its pretty similar like yours but I'm just setting the date with echoing PHP variable.

Comment: I have tried your code and still didn't get anything... Is it so that I'm using different jquery ui version? `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: Version of jquery ui  should not affect , I think so.

Comment: This thread is old but for anyone tempted to copy/paste: I believe the code in this answer will set all input controls with class 'datepicker' to the value of the single input control with ID 'date'.

Comment: @TonyG, Yes you are correct . Answer is just how you can set date  . It is up to  you how you will use class and id.

Answer (score 0):

Mine situation was my date input didn't show the date value I picked after submit, but the date value can be seen in Chrome Developer tool, so I solved this problem by getting the input value before setting datepicker, then adding the value after.

```
$( function() {
    var ddate = document.getElementById("date").value?document.getElementById("date").value:'';
    $("#date").datepicker();
    $("#date").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy/mm/dd");
    $("#date").val(ddate);
} );
```